# How to access promise value outside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, stripe-payments

I'm trying to understand how promises, callbacks etc work in node.js, particularly in the case of accessing the value outside of the function. I've spent time going through the answers here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and here [call Stripe API with await](http://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/45618523/call-stripe-api-with-await) but every variation I try I always end up with 'subscription' outside the function as undefined.

Thanks

```
let subscription;
async function getSub(){
    subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('sub_HurxwcQoCIH7jv');
    // code here only executes _after_ the request is done?
    return subscription
}
getSub()
console.log("subscription: ", subscription) // subscription undefined??
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can get a response

```
getSub()
.then(subscription => {
    console.log("subscription: ", subscription);
});
```

Or

```
const funcA = async() {
    const subscription  = await getSub();
    console.log("subscription: ", subscription);
}
funcA();
```

Comment: First function throw error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" - remove `;` after console.log`;`

Comment: Thanks. However, 'subscription' is still undefined outside of getSub() & functA. My aim is to 'export' the variable for use elsewhere in the parent scope eg. in the original position of my console.log()

Comment: the async method returns promise, in order to resolve/reject it you must either chain it with then or use await keyword, for await keyword you again need an async method. If you want it to be available in global scope you will need to nest everything inside .then or inside the await method.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. At least I understand a bit more why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

The code *written after* the async function is *executes AFTER* the sync function but getting done BEFORE the async function so it will be undefined as set in the first line `let subscription // undefined`

Lets cut it into pieces and number the chronology of happens:

```
1. let subscription;
2. async function getSub(){
    5. subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('sub_HurxwcQoCIH7jv');
    // code here only executes _after_ the request is done?
    6. return subscription
}
3. getSub()
4. console.log("subscription: ", subscription) // subscription undefined??
```

So as you can see, the console log will happen BEFORE the assignment because **2.** takes longer than **3.** and **4.** because of **5.** in it.

You should do something like this:

```
(async () => {
  const sub = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve('sub_HurxwcQoCIH7jv')
  console.log(sub) //
})()
```

You can also name the function:

```
const functionWithSomeName = async () => {
  const sub = await ...CODE HERE...
  console.log(sub)
}

functionWithSomeName()
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it is happening, I'm just not sure how to make the variable available for use elsewhere in the parent scope eg. in the original position of my console.log(). In these functions 'subscription' will still be undefined outside of these functions.

Comment: You should build the code so it will can access it the way I showed you.
So your code should wrap this function from first of all.
Your code should run in async function and execute this and then you can access it anywhere down.

Comment: You also shouldn't return the value.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll have to rethink how to restructure my code.